# Semi-supervised method for identifying states and state durations in a time series for anomaly detection

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, outliers, hidden-markov-model, semi-supervised-learning

I am developing a semi-supervised method for identifying anomalies in a time series with multiple states. Let's consider this example time series in which there are two states e.g. state 1 and 2 with mean power 0 and 100, respectively.

[image]

As we can see, whenever the system enters into a particular state, it stays there for a fixed amount of time (with some variance) before transitioning into another state during the normal operation. e.g. 20 seconds in state 1, and 40 seconds in state 2, approximately. I am looking for an semi-supervised method to detect the anomalous state in which system enters into that state but stays there for a long/short period of time than the usual duration, as marked in read in the above figure.

So there are two obvious questions to ask here:

1. Identifying the number of states from the give time series. I use a clustering method (such as k-means) to find it.
2. Learning the state properties such as power-level and state duration.

I am able to detect the states and their corresponding power level (or fitting to a distribution) using a HMM from the given normal time series. But how to learn the state duration? After learning these parameters, I am planning to use a finite state machine to model the states and their properties to detect the anomalies in an online manner. Any suggestions??

Answer (score -1):

If you can detect via k-means how many distinct groups there are ...In your example 5 then you can estimate each of the interval lengths . If you have 4 interval lengths as in this case say 4,5,4,5 and say ? for the most recent then why not test the hypothesis that the "?" is significantly different from the average of the first  4 previous intervals. This could be done by setting up a pulse indicator (0,0,0,0,1) as a regressor and testing the hypothesis for the significance of this suggested regressor. The whole idea would be determine ? for a particular level of confidence and then sense if the actual interval exceeds ?